What are the parameters in the "SOCKET" struct in the winsock API?
I came across the usage of select(...,fd_set,...) in winsock to check on multiple sockets at once without blocking the application. But it needs the input fd_set.
this is what fd_set looks like:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-fd_set
typedef struct fd_set {
  u_int  fd_count;
  SOCKET fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];
}

Now if I understand correctly fd_set needs the parameter fd_array[] which has the data type "SOCKET".
I unfortunatly couldn't find anything regarding the struct named "SOCKET" which leads to my question:
What are the parameters in the "SOCKET" struct in the winsock API?

SOCKET is an alias for int. It's a generally handle to an open socket.

That makes sense, because accept() also returns an int as a handle for the new socket. thank you!

You're not meant to manipulate struct fd_set objects directly, and you don't need to know anything about their internal structure.  The documentation page for the select() function (German) describes the four standard macros, FD_CLR(), FD_ISSET(), FD_SET(), and FD_ZERO() that you're supposed to use to work with fd_sets.

The internal contents of fd_set differ from one OS to another, that is why the FD_xxx macros exist for code portability.
